# GKE docker image pull extremely slow with low RAM node machine types

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am deploying onto a cluster on GKE and image pulling seems to be sometimes untenably slow and also wildly inconsistent. Are these times really what is considered acceptable, or might it indicate a problem in my config somewhere?

The artifact registry is europe-west2 and I have spun up a cluster (1.21.5-gke.1302) in europe-west2-a. Other than making it single node and using EC2 'small' instances instead of medium I have stuck with the defaults, other than trying with Image streaming both enabled and disabled (which seems to make no difference - at least to first deployment.)

Pulling times:

- k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.0.4 takes up to 6.5 minutes
- redis takes up to 10 minutes
- my own image (hosted on the artifact repository - around 3.5G) takes up to 30 minutes
- another of my own images (hosted on the artifact repository - around 1G) has taken only 53 seconds, however.

It seems to get slower the further through the deployment it gets, which takes about an hour in total. Can anyone think of any config issues that may be causing this? I'm thinking possibly some API limits that I'm not aware of, kubelet download speeds, or too many concurrent downloads...

--- Edit

As I typed the above, I had an idea, and it turns out to be the answer. The type of instance makes a difference. I tried again with a cluster using 'medium' EC2 (so 4G of RAM instead of 2G) and it deployed in 15 minutes rather than an hour, again getting noticeably slower pull speeds after (I assume?) the 4G mark is somehow met. I then made a cluster with 'e2-standard-2' (now 8G of RAM) and that totalled only 3.5 minutes! (But again with this attenuation in pull speed as the deployment went on.)

I had assumed that the images would be downloaded onto a 'real' disk, but maybe all space on my cluster is virtualised in some way and so the RAM size makes a difference even for deployment? But if this is the case and there's no underlying filesystem to provide swap space, I'm once again confused since then a 3G image shouldn't download at all on 2G of RAM! So my new question is why does this make a difference? I would like to have a cluster of nodes that serve the purpose of my app, not that are overpowered just so I can deploy in a reasonable time. (Tin-foil hat time - is it possible this is as designed by Google to encourage people to use the more expensive option?)

Comment: I notice you posting the problems on the day of big google problems with gmail, youtube etc.. in europe region specifically. Could it be related? Cloud status console shows networking issue.

Comment: As @Hitobat commented, there was a major outage in Google Europe, please discard this.
Also you can try to use the Image streaming to pull container images, this can reduce the amount of time to pull images. https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/image-streaming

Comment: The outage is an excellent insight, but I have been aware of this problem for over a couple of weeks now, and the amount of RAM definitely makes a difference. I have also tried using image streaming and it makes no significant difference on the first pull.

Comment: How large is your disk? Disk speed is related to the size. File system cache can help speed based on available system RAM but only temporary.

Comment: check image pull policy, https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/ . "Always" might induce slowness.

Comment: Were you able to check the image pull policy? Did you get any improvement using it?

Comment: @Vicente Ayala I am only seeing the problem on the initial deployment having spun up a new server - the issue is with the amount of time it takes to make the pull rather than the frequency with which it does it.

Comment: @Hitobat I'm running on Google Cloud Platform and have spun up one of their clusters. I believe they have 64G disks. I also don't know how I might turn file system caching on, but again I would only expect that to work with a pre-pulled file, and my issues is solely on first deployment.